# <pre> tag is not adapting the column width in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap CSS to style my page. When I am using the `<pre>...</pre>` tag inside the `class="col"` then it is not adapting the width of the column instead of that it is increasing the width of the whole column. But when I am using the `class="col-lg-8"` it is working fine

#### HTML Code

```html
<div class="col">
    <pre>
          <code>
             ...
          </code>
    </pre>
</div>
```

#### With `<pre>` tag and `class="col"`

[image: With pre tag it is increasing the width of column]

#### With `<pre>` tag and `class="col-lg-8"`

[image]

#### Without `<pre>` tag

[image]

#### Check it live here

https://thelovekesh.github.io/cbtheme-debug/blog/

Comment: How can we debug your output? :)

Comment: @m4n0 I have shared the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of the flex box.

We could add `min-width: 0` to our columns to override the default behavior.